# Extract Specific Data from Txt file python

Tags: python, logfile

I have a txt.fil (server log) and want to extract only certain fields from it and write it to csv:

```
Date=2021-01-04 23:45:47.131 interaction=basic id=12333 personalid=11117 tisract=jinx fabrics=xyz session_id=adsflkixx endpoint=tool/tac/product/case
```

There are basically millions of lines like this

how can I only extract date, id, and endpoint from the txt file and convert it maybe to dict and then to data frame?

The names are repeating the values keep changing, so I would like to keep the names as the header and the values as the rows of data.

Comment: Use regex or grok - https://pypi.org/project/pygrok/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a more suited tool like the ELK Stack for log parsing, but if you want to use Python...

Use a regex

```
import re
import csv

regex = r"^Date=(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} (?:\d{2}:){2}\d{2}\.\d{3})\W.*\sid=(\d+).*\sendpoint=(.+)$"

with open('log.txt') as f, open('out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
  fields = ["Date", "id", "endpoint"]
  writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=fields)
  writer.writeheader()
  for line in f:
    matches = re.finditer(regex, line, re.MULTILINE)
    for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
      data = {fields[groupNum]: match.group(groupNum + 1) for groupNum in range(len(match.groups()))}
      writer.writerow(data)
```

Sample output

```
$ cat out.csv
Date,id,endpoint
2021-01-04 23:45:47.131,12333,tool/tac/product/case
```

Comment: One problem that still persist is: some lines does not have some variables like say endpoint. So, it will skip that line all together. What I would love to do is, just add "nan"  or leave it empty if there is no endpoint.  The column would be there; if the column name is present, it will get the value and populate it,  else it will add "nan" or leave it empty.

Comment: Look at what the `?` regex group operator does